# REST : Which action do I use for batch processing?

Tags: http, rest, batch-processing

I've got an XML document which may hold one or more entities. For the sake of this example, let's say those entities are cars.

Now, I'm about to create a REST service which accepts the XML file and carries out create, update and delete operations. I thought I'd simply do :

> **HTTP POST to /service/car** : create cars listed in the in XML document
>
> **HTTP PUT to /service/car** : update cars listed in the in XML document
>
> **HTTP DELETE to /service/var** : delete cars listed in the in XML document

However, it is my impression that PUT and DELETE should act on resources (URL's) which represents a specific entity. That is, I could invoke a HTTP DELETE against /service/car/10 to delete car number 10. However, the HTTP/1.1 specification states that

> The PUT method requests that the enclosed entity be stored under the
>   supplied Request-URI

This means that I can't simply use a PUT to flag an update operation, I should also add the car id to the URL. However, I've got multiple cars which needs to be batch updated.

I'm tempted to do :

> **HTTP POST to /service/car/create**
>
> **HTTP POST to /service/car/update**
>
> **HTTP POST to /service/car/delete**

However, something tells me that this isn't quite how you do things with REST.

Are there any "best practise" on this?

Answer (score 0):

I would think about the XML document as a "command" resource you're "RESTing" and not the cars. The semantic of the resource type would be "cars-modification-command". I would define an URI `/modifications/cars`. The HTTP answer would be a list of URIs which could be queried for the result of the command, e.g. the URI for the new cars.

It's a similar question as "[how to do I do complex queries in REST-style](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18930471/2615437)"? My answer would be: make the query (or in this case: the modification command) a full fledged object of your domain.