# Web api odata sending a long $filter string results in maxurlstring exceeds error

Tags: asp.net-web-api, odata, asp.net-web-api-odata

I am trying to send a large $filter string to my webapi odata endpoint.But it gives me error saying the size of request headers are too long/maxurlstringlength exceeds.

Is there a way to send the $filter in "POST" request and query the odata endpoint? i cannot use the batch statement as i am using .net framework 4.0.

Comment: You can always increase the query string length in web.config see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e1f13641%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Comment: @eoghank- But is it a good practice to increase the query string length to a big value?

Comment: About 2000 chars is considered the limit - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/417142/what-is-the-maximum-length-of-a-url-in-different-browsers. Is your $filter query string longer than this? That seems very large.