# breezeJs : ODATA Url limitation

Tags: odata, breeze

I've got a query with many "contains" filters and I've reached the URL limitation (well over 2000 characters).

I've come across this post ([OData Url Length Limitations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4247985/odata-url-length-limitations)), which solution is to use the $batch feature of ODATA.

Is there a way to do that with breeze ?

Answer (score 1):

If you are willing to sidestep OData a bit, use the [withParameters](http://www.getbreezenow.com/documentation/querying-depth#withParameters) feature to pass filter parameters to the server method.  Then you can send the parameters in a more compact representation than OData uses.  Note the [second example in docs](http://www.getbreezenow.com/documentation/querying-depth#withParameters), in which an array is passed as a parameter.

If that's still too big, then you can use the [ajaxpost adapter](http://www.getbreezenow.com/documentation/breezeajaxpostjs), which allows you to send query parameters using POST.  Then the sky's the limit.

Comment: Thanks Steve. The withParameters solution is actually the one I've started implementing before I asked the question here. It's definitely not as neat as using purely ODATA but it works.

Comment: Remember that you can mix `withParameters` with other query operations.  So you could use `withParameters` for your "contains" filters, and still use `where`, `skip`, `take`, `orderBy` for everything else.

Answer (score 0):

I'd look into writing a Breeze *DataServiceAdapter* that inherits from the 'OData' adapter you're currently [using as described here](http://www.getbreezenow.com/documentation/dataserviceadapters).

You'd override its `executeQuery` method and do something appropriate when the URL gets too big.

The [`executeQuery` method for the stock 'OData' adapter](https://github.com/Breeze/breeze.js/blob/master/src/b00_breeze.dataService.odata.js#L37) is only 22 lines so it shouldn't be daunting.

You will note, however, that this adapter delegates to *datajs*. That means you'll have to figure out what facilities *datajs* offers for doing the $batch trick that you described. I don't know the answer to that myself. We'd all like to learn from you.

Comment: Thanks Ward. I understand the idea. That however, involves more work and I'm not sure I have time for this. I will take a look at the datajs code though.